# Multi-Resolution in Android?

Tags: java, android, image

I have been going through to achieve Multi-Resolution in android built in eclipse.

I have this app where i have used a lot of images, firstly the only limitation i have is size, i cannot exceed 5MB size for the app, surprisingly i was able to do this by just storing only in the xxhdpi folder, not all of the dpi folders, such as ldpi, mdpi and above xxhdpi devices dont support the app.

As you can see if i store all the folders with the respective images, it makes the app of size almost 15MB. I have read in forums that in cocos2dx there is a function to which only image is provided, which automatically scales the image with the device, and returns it to be set respectively,

i was wondering if there is a way to do this in android as well, thanx in advance

Comment: Android will automatically scale your images if you have not provided specific images for that particular density. Read more here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch Also read about nine-patch images for android

Comment: Wouldn't be better I am afraid. Due to limited support he'd still need to use either 3rd party library or rasterize SVGs to further use. A bit of hassle

Comment: @DerGol...lum will try the SVG approach, what are these 3rd party libraries and where can i find them, can they scale my image as that is my requirement

Comment: although this is not what i was looking for, but WTH, if this process gets me what i want to do i will accept this as an answer, @DerGol...lum, would you write this in an answer so when i meet my requirement i could tick mark it

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `SVG` (vectorial images) files, through a 3rd party library.
`SVGs` are scalable (up or down, doesn't really matter) without loosing definition, due to their vectorial nature (it's just an `xml` file with geometrical definitions and color transitions).

This way, you'd have only 1 version of the graphical file and then only get the desired bitmap from it, with no ugly pixellation.

The most used libraries so far are [android-svg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) and [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/), primarily (there are a few other ones, and some variants to the proposed ones too).
Scaling is what they are meant to: you provide the `SVG` file (possibly in your `raw` or `assets` folder) and the needed dimensions (in pixels).
And get your bitmapped image out of the vectors.

Fantastic.

Our user [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau) is the author of [AndroidSVG](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) and he always lends a friendly support to whom needs a hand with his library.